How to Generate a Padded Random Number as a Variable in Insomnia REST Client
I'm working with the Insomnia REST client and I'm trying to generate a zero-padded random number between 000 and 999 to use as part of a request. I want to create an environment variable that calculates this padded number so I can use it in multiple requests.
Here's what I've tried so far:
{{ ('000' + (1000 | random)) | slice(-3) }}
I put this line in an environment variable but the live preview shows an error, and when used in a request, it only outputs the text before the variable call, like this:
{
  "transactionId": "Testing_{{ paddedRange }}"
}

I get the result Testing_ without the padded random number.
I need to define a variable that evaluates to a random number with leading zeros when it's less than three digits. What is the correct way to do this in Insomnia?
Things I have considered:
Insomnia might not support chaining filters or certain Nunjucks functionality.
Live preview does not seem to execute the random number generation.
My question:
How can I correctly create a zero-padded random number variable within Insomnia's environment? Is there a known limitation I should be aware of, or is there an alternative approach that I can take?

Insomnia doesn't support the exact equivalent of Postman's Pre-request Scripts directly within GUI. I recommended use Postman's Pre-request Scripts. It can generate random number  of zero padded. You can access it from body of JSON data in you REST endpoint call.
